# Open a new widget, arrange buttons. Python, KIVY

Tags: python, kivy

With this code, what I'm trying to do is, group and display a few buttons next to each other and on press each button opens an app.

PY File

```
class CustomPopup(popup):
    pass


class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):
    help_me_button = Button(text='HELP ME')
    help_me_button.bind(on_press=self.open_helpme)
    games_button = Button(text='GAMES')
    games_button.bind(on_press=self.open_games)

    buttons = BoxLayout(orientation='horizontal')
    buttons.add_widget(help_me_button)
    buttons.add_widget(game_button)


    return layout

def open_help_me(self, help_me):
    p = self.popup

    p = Popup(content=help_me,
              title='Help Me',
              size_hint=(0.8, 0.8))

        if p.content is not help_me:
            p.content = help_me
        p.open()
    else:
        super(HelpMeApp, self).display_helpme(HelpMe)
```

Every time I run the program it says popup not define or the application runs and shuts down immediately, can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong. I'm new to programming.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I did the the question.

Answer (score 1):

p = self.popup should not be there. You try to access "self.popup" which is undefined - next line you're doing the right thing, you're creating a new Popup (done by writing p = Popup(...))